# Posting questions/answers and editing does not work with Iron 3.0.197.0

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-declined, google-chrome, 500-server-error

That's strange because Iron is [very similar](http://www.srware.net/en/software_srware_iron_chrome_vs_iron.php) to Chrome, and I am able to post questions/answers with Chrome 3.0.195.33 (just checked).

With Iron, I get redicted to the **"Oops! Something Bad Happened!"** - error page, where I am *asked* to report the problem to Meta if I think it's interesting.

I posted this issue here a few days before but the old question is gone. It might have been deleted due to 'being too localized', as someone told me.

**Feature wish:**

If a user with an unusual browser gets to the error page, they should be told to use a supported browser *instead of asking them to submit a bug report to Meta* -- as this would just be a waste of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't test on every single browser ever released, but every major browser is known to work:

IE6, IE7, IE8, Safari2, Safari3, Chrome1, Chrome2, Chrome3, Firefox2, Firefox3, Firefox3.5, Opera9, Opera10

Again: even *Opera* works.

I'd say **that browser is clearly broken**; you shouldn't be filing the bug here, but with whoever wrote it.

Comment: There are other browsers?

Comment: @random: `links`

Comment: Shouldn't that be `lynx`?

Comment: @Cigars...: it's only `lynx` if you don't want tables and frames and fun things like that.  otherwise use `links`.

Comment: I didn't assume that you test the site on every single browser ever released. I submitted this bug because the SO error page *asked* me to do it and I like the site enough to invest this time. Making the error page more clear, i.e. describing *what kinds* of bugs you deem *irrelevant*, would have saved my time (and yours). FYI I thought this issues might be of interest because 1) Iron = Chrome + *newer* libs 2) it works stable for all kinds of other complex sites and 3) this issue hasn't been there a few days before. That's all.

Comment: That's fine, but you need to file the bug with whoever makes IronChrome, not us. We're not broken!